# Soft-restart tampers with physics determinism, resulting in different results

Tags: unity, physics

#### Updated question

I have a `Spawner` entity that spawns my `Rollable`s:

```
// Spawner.cs
public abstract class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract T Spawn<T>(T prefab) where T : Component;
}

// PositionSpawner.cs
public abstract class PositionSpawner : Spawner
{
    public override T Spawn<T>(T entity)
    {
        T spawnedEntity = Instantiate(entity);
        spawnedEntity.transform.position = transform.position;
        spawnedEntity.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;

        return spawnedEntity;
    }
}

// RollableSpawner.cs
public sealed class RollableSpawner : PositionSpawner
{
    public Rollable Spawn(Rollable entity)
    {
        Rollable rollable = base.Spawn<Rollable>(entity);

        Restore(rollable);

        return rollable;
    }

    public void Restore(Rollable entity)
    {
        Quaternion r = transform.rotation;
        Vector3 p = transform.position + transform.up * (entity.Radius + 0.05f);

        entity.transform.rotation = r;
        entity.transform.position = p;

        entity.Rigidbody.rotation = r;
        entity.Rigidbody.position = p;

        entity.Restore();
    }
}
```

The `Rollable` though, is quite a big one and somewhat coupled with `RollableCollider` - [found, fully, here](https://gist.github.com/joltmode/af735c68162240a356b55af090e71ba4).

The `Restore` method:

```
public void Restore()
{
    rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    rigidbody.Sleep();

    inAir = Drowning = false;

    Speed = 0f;
    Altitude = 0f;
    UnShift();

    UpdateDirectionality();
    UpdateOrientedTransform();

    ClearGateEventRegistry(gateEntryEvents);
    ClearGateEventRegistry(gateExitEvents);
    ResetSoakedParts();

    StopCoroutine(sleepingRoutine);
    StopCoroutine(gateRoutine);

    rigidbody.WakeUp();

    UpdateInAir();

    sleepingRoutine = StartCoroutine(SleepingRoutine());
    gateRoutine = StartCoroutine(GateRoutine());

    previouslyBackwards = false; Backwards = false;
}
```

And, to reset, I am calling `RollableSpawner.Restore()` with a push of a button.

The problem here is that even if after reset all of the values are as expected - position/rotation are *correct*, velocities and everything else - the `Rollable` still ends up taking a slightly different trajectory each time.

Though, that's only noticeable with soft-reset.

If I am to play/stop/replay the scene - the `Rollable` always takes the same trajectory.

Why is it that upon soft-reset the `Rollable` - while having the same properties - ends up in different trajectories, yet, hard-reset doesn't?

And... how do I fix it?

P.S. As for what have I tried.. Switching `Sleep()`/`WakeUp()` to `isKinematic`. But to be honest, I don't even have a clue what to attempt.

Comment: This looks like an [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If I understand correctly, what you *want* is determinism: repeatable results after a quick-restart. You *think* that a physics engine reset could be *a route to achieve that*, but focusing the question on this approach may exclude other workable solutions. Would you consider reframing this question in terms of determinism in your quick-reset feature, and share the relevant parts of your quick-restart code? This may help find other possible fixes.

Comment: It seems you're looking more for how to make Unity's physics engine deterministic as even a "quick restart" would require the same physics simulation to be performed which means a deterministic physics engine.

Comment: @DMGregory yeah, thought about it right as I asked. To be reframed...

Comment: @Coburn Unity's physics engine (PhysX) is as deterministic as deterministic is floating point value. Which makes it fully deterministic on exactly the same environment.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say in your comment. Regardless, PhysX is not deterministic, see http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx_knowledge_base.html

Comment: @joltmode just so you know, besides Unity's physics engine not being deterministic, it's not deterministic, even on the same exact machine. Even FPS from varying CPU changes break the determinism of the engine (remember FixedUpdate can be called 0-X times a frame too, which breaks determinism if using values like input that are changed in Update)

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix even if so, I am still looking to fix the issue where hard-reset results in 1:1 trajectory all of the times, but soft-reset messes things up.

Comment: @joltmode are you resetting --velocity--? Never mind, I see you are in the bottom script, velocity is the main thing I'd check, isKinematic is supposed to reset forces, are you sure you're not keeping a reference to the objects somewhere and having them keep moving (for example, a coroutine?)